# Fixing the adapter construtcor for arraylist

Tags: android

I am learning android , I am having this error that i didn't know how to solve

error `The constructor is undefined` in the parameter of the adapter `getdata()`

```
   adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
```

I know the constructor of Gridviewadapter for the arraylist should be fixed .. but how?

```
public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Listitem> data) {
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
this.mcontext =context;
}
```

this is code

```
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String url = c.getString(TAG_URL);
            Listitem.add(new Listitem(id,url));
        }

        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

getdata()

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://justedhak.comlu.com/get-data.php");

        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        myJSON=result;
        showList();
    }
```

Comment: the error is caused due to `getData()` function, please post whole code including `getData()` functionality.

Comment: @vipul_asri check my edit plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this.

to get your data from server call this line from your oncreate method

```
GetDataJSON .execute();
```

and you class will be like this.

```
public class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask{
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://justedhak.comlu.com/get-data.php");

        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        myJSON=result;
        showList();
    }
}
```

and your method showList will be like.

```
protected void showList(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String url = c.getString(TAG_URL);
                Listitem.add(new Listitem(id,url));
            }

            adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, Listitem);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you check this question plz ? its realted to this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926948/what-is-the-cause-of-org-json-jsonexception-no-value-for-url